# Is it possible to find the time taken by millis?

Tags: time, millis

The function `millis` would be running in the span of 100+ microseconds or less. Is there a reliable way to go about measuring the time taken by a single millis call?

One approach that comes to mind is using `micros`, however, a call to `micros` will include the time taken by the function call of `micros` itself as well, so depending on how long micros takes, the measurement for `millis` may be off.

I need to find this as an application I am working on requires accurate time measurements for every step taken in the code, including `millis`.

Comment: Can you clarify what you are asking here? Are you trying to get accurate times from millis() or are you trying to work out how long it takes to call the function millis()?

Comment: @Cybergibbons How long a call to `miilis` takes.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

If you want to know *exactly* how long something will take, there is only one solution: Look at the disassembly!

Starting with the minimal code:

```
void setup(){};

volatile uint16_t x;
void loop()
{
  x = millis();

}
```

This code compiled and then fed into `avr-objdump -S` produces a documented disassembly. Here are the interesting excerpts:

`void loop()` produces:

```
000000a8 <loop>:
  a8:   0e 94 a7 00     call    0x14e   ; 0x14e <millis>
  ac:   60 93 00 01     sts 0x0100, r22
  b0:   70 93 01 01     sts 0x0101, r23
  b4:   80 93 02 01     sts 0x0102, r24
  b8:   90 93 03 01     sts 0x0103, r25
  bc:   08 95           ret
```

Which is a function call (`call`), four copies (which copy each of the bytes in the `uint32_t` return value of `millis()` (note that the arduino docs call this a `long`, but they are incorrect to not be explicitly specifying the variable sizes)), and finally the function return.

`call` requires 4 clock cycles, and each `sts` requires 2 clock cycles, so we have a minimum of 12 clock cycles just for function call overhead.

Now, lets look at the disassembly of the `<millis>` function, which is located at `0x14e`:

```
unsigned long millis()
{
    unsigned long m;
    uint8_t oldSREG = SREG;
 14e:   8f b7           in  r24, 0x3f   ; 63

    // disable interrupts while we read timer0_millis or we might get an
    // inconsistent value (e.g. in the middle of a write to timer0_millis)
    cli();
 150:   f8 94           cli
    m = timer0_millis;
 152:   20 91 08 01     lds r18, 0x0108
 156:   30 91 09 01     lds r19, 0x0109
 15a:   40 91 0a 01     lds r20, 0x010A
 15e:   50 91 0b 01     lds r21, 0x010B
    SREG = oldSREG;
 162:   8f bf           out 0x3f, r24   ; 63

    return m;
}
 164:   b9 01           movw    r22, r18
 166:   ca 01           movw    r24, r20
 168:   08 95           ret
```

As you can see, the `millis()` function is fairly simple:

1. `in` saves the interrupt register settings (1 cycle)
2. `cli` turns off the interrupts (1 cycle)
3. `lds` copy one of the 4 bytes of the current value of the milli counter into a temporary register (2 clock cycles)
4. `lds` Byte 2 (2 clock cycles)
5. `lds` Byte 3 (2 clock cycles)
6. `lds` Byte 4 (2 clock cycles)
7. `out` restore interrupt settings (1 clock cycle)
8. `movw` shuffle registers around (1 clock cycle)
9. `movw` and again (1 clock cycle)
10. `ret` return from subroutine  (4 cycles)

So, if we add them all up, we have a total of 17 clock cycles in the `millis()` function itself, plus a call overhead of 12, for a total of 29 clock cycles.

Assuming a 16 Mhz clock rate (most arduinos), each clock cycle is `1 / 16e6` seconds, or 0.0000000625 seconds, which is 62.5 nanoseconds. 62.5 ns * 29 = 1.812 microseconds.

Therefore, the total execution time for a single `millis()` call on *most* Arduinos will be **1.812 microseconds**.

---

[AVR Assembly reference](http://www.atmel.com/images/doc0856.pdf)

<sub>As a side-note, there is space for optimization here! If you update the `unsigned long millis(){}` function definition to be `inline unsigned long millis(){}`, you would remove the call overhead (at the cost of *slightly* larger code size). Furthermore, it looks like the compiler is doing two unnecessary moves (the two `movw` calls, but I haven't looked at it that closely).</sub>

<sub>Really, considering the function call overhead is 5 instructions, and the actual *contents* of the `millis()` function is only 6 instructions, I think the `millis()` function should really be `inline` by default, but the Arduino codebase is rather poorly optimized.</sub>

---

Here is the full disassemby for anyone interested:

```
sketch_feb13a.cpp.elf:     file format elf32-avr


Disassembly of section .text:

00000000 <__vectors>:
    SREG = oldSREG;

    return m;
}

unsigned long micros() {
   0:   0c 94 34 00     jmp 0x68    ; 0x68 <__ctors_end>
   4:   0c 94 51 00     jmp 0xa2    ; 0xa2 <__bad_interrupt>
   8:   0c 94 51 00     jmp 0xa2    ; 0xa2 <__bad_interrupt>
   c:   0c 94 51 00     jmp 0xa2    ; 0xa2 <__bad_interrupt>
  10:   0c 94 51 00     jmp 0xa2    ; 0xa2 <__bad_interrupt>
  14:   0c 94 51 00     jmp 0xa2    ; 0xa2 <__bad_interrupt>
  18:   0c 94 51 00     jmp 0xa2    ; 0xa2 <__bad_interrupt>
  1c:   0c 94 51 00     jmp 0xa2    ; 0xa2 <__bad_interrupt>
  20:   0c 94 51 00     jmp 0xa2    ; 0xa2 <__bad_interrupt>
  24:   0c 94 51 00     jmp 0xa2    ; 0xa2 <__bad_interrupt>
  28:   0c 94 51 00     jmp 0xa2    ; 0xa2 <__bad_interrupt>
  2c:   0c 94 51 00     jmp 0xa2    ; 0xa2 <__bad_interrupt>
  30:   0c 94 51 00     jmp 0xa2    ; 0xa2 <__bad_interrupt>
  34:   0c 94 51 00     jmp 0xa2    ; 0xa2 <__bad_interrupt>
  38:   0c 94 51 00     jmp 0xa2    ; 0xa2 <__bad_interrupt>
  3c:   0c 94 51 00     jmp 0xa2    ; 0xa2 <__bad_interrupt>
  40:   0c 94 5f 00     jmp 0xbe    ; 0xbe <__vector_16>
  44:   0c 94 51 00     jmp 0xa2    ; 0xa2 <__bad_interrupt>
  48:   0c 94 51 00     jmp 0xa2    ; 0xa2 <__bad_interrupt>
  4c:   0c 94 51 00     jmp 0xa2    ; 0xa2 <__bad_interrupt>
  50:   0c 94 51 00     jmp 0xa2    ; 0xa2 <__bad_interrupt>
  54:   0c 94 51 00     jmp 0xa2    ; 0xa2 <__bad_interrupt>
  58:   0c 94 51 00     jmp 0xa2    ; 0xa2 <__bad_interrupt>
  5c:   0c 94 51 00     jmp 0xa2    ; 0xa2 <__bad_interrupt>
  60:   0c 94 51 00     jmp 0xa2    ; 0xa2 <__bad_interrupt>
  64:   0c 94 51 00     jmp 0xa2    ; 0xa2 <__bad_interrupt>

00000068 <__ctors_end>:
  68:   11 24           eor r1, r1
  6a:   1f be           out 0x3f, r1    ; 63
  6c:   cf ef           ldi r28, 0xFF   ; 255
  6e:   d8 e0           ldi r29, 0x08   ; 8
  70:   de bf           out 0x3e, r29   ; 62
  72:   cd bf           out 0x3d, r28   ; 61

00000074 <__do_copy_data>:
  74:   11 e0           ldi r17, 0x01   ; 1
  76:   a0 e0           ldi r26, 0x00   ; 0
  78:   b1 e0           ldi r27, 0x01   ; 1
  7a:   e2 e0           ldi r30, 0x02   ; 2
  7c:   f2 e0           ldi r31, 0x02   ; 2
  7e:   02 c0           rjmp    .+4         ; 0x84 <.do_copy_data_start>

00000080 <.do_copy_data_loop>:
  80:   05 90           lpm r0, Z+
  82:   0d 92           st  X+, r0

00000084 <.do_copy_data_start>:
  84:   a0 30           cpi r26, 0x00   ; 0
  86:   b1 07           cpc r27, r17
  88:   d9 f7           brne    .-10        ; 0x80 <.do_copy_data_loop>

0000008a <__do_clear_bss>:
  8a:   11 e0           ldi r17, 0x01   ; 1
  8c:   a0 e0           ldi r26, 0x00   ; 0
  8e:   b1 e0           ldi r27, 0x01   ; 1
  90:   01 c0           rjmp    .+2         ; 0x94 <.do_clear_bss_start>

00000092 <.do_clear_bss_loop>:
  92:   1d 92           st  X+, r1

00000094 <.do_clear_bss_start>:
  94:   ad 30           cpi r26, 0x0D   ; 13
  96:   b1 07           cpc r27, r17
  98:   e1 f7           brne    .-8         ; 0x92 <.do_clear_bss_loop>
  9a:   0e 94 f0 00     call    0x1e0   ; 0x1e0 <main>
  9e:   0c 94 ff 00     jmp 0x1fe   ; 0x1fe <_exit>

000000a2 <__bad_interrupt>:
  a2:   0c 94 00 00     jmp 0   ; 0x0 <__vectors>

000000a6 <setup>:
  a6:   08 95           ret

000000a8 <loop>:
  a8:   0e 94 a7 00     call    0x14e   ; 0x14e <millis>
  ac:   60 93 00 01     sts 0x0100, r22
  b0:   70 93 01 01     sts 0x0101, r23
  b4:   80 93 02 01     sts 0x0102, r24
  b8:   90 93 03 01     sts 0x0103, r25
  bc:   08 95           ret

000000be <__vector_16>:
#if defined(__AVR_ATtiny24__) || defined(__AVR_ATtiny44__) || defined(__AVR_ATtiny84__)
ISR(TIM0_OVF_vect)
#else
ISR(TIMER0_OVF_vect)
#endif
{
  be:   1f 92           push    r1
  c0:   0f 92           push    r0
  c2:   0f b6           in  r0, 0x3f    ; 63
  c4:   0f 92           push    r0
  c6:   11 24           eor r1, r1
  c8:   2f 93           push    r18
  ca:   3f 93           push    r19
  cc:   8f 93           push    r24
  ce:   9f 93           push    r25
  d0:   af 93           push    r26
  d2:   bf 93           push    r27
    // copy these to local variables so they can be stored in registers
    // (volatile variables must be read from memory on every access)
    unsigned long m = timer0_millis;
  d4:   80 91 08 01     lds r24, 0x0108
  d8:   90 91 09 01     lds r25, 0x0109
  dc:   a0 91 0a 01     lds r26, 0x010A
  e0:   b0 91 0b 01     lds r27, 0x010B
    unsigned char f = timer0_fract;
  e4:   30 91 0c 01     lds r19, 0x010C

    m += MILLIS_INC;
  e8:   01 96           adiw    r24, 0x01   ; 1
  ea:   a1 1d           adc r26, r1
  ec:   b1 1d           adc r27, r1
    f += FRACT_INC;
  ee:   23 2f           mov r18, r19
  f0:   2d 5f           subi    r18, 0xFD   ; 253
    if (f >= FRACT_MAX) {
  f2:   2d 37           cpi r18, 0x7D   ; 125
  f4:   20 f0           brcs    .+8         ; 0xfe <__vector_16+0x40>
        f -= FRACT_MAX;
  f6:   2d 57           subi    r18, 0x7D   ; 125
        m += 1;
  f8:   01 96           adiw    r24, 0x01   ; 1
  fa:   a1 1d           adc r26, r1
  fc:   b1 1d           adc r27, r1
    }

    timer0_fract = f;
  fe:   20 93 0c 01     sts 0x010C, r18
    timer0_millis = m;
 102:   80 93 08 01     sts 0x0108, r24
 106:   90 93 09 01     sts 0x0109, r25
 10a:   a0 93 0a 01     sts 0x010A, r26
 10e:   b0 93 0b 01     sts 0x010B, r27
    timer0_overflow_count++;
 112:   80 91 04 01     lds r24, 0x0104
 116:   90 91 05 01     lds r25, 0x0105
 11a:   a0 91 06 01     lds r26, 0x0106
 11e:   b0 91 07 01     lds r27, 0x0107
 122:   01 96           adiw    r24, 0x01   ; 1
 124:   a1 1d           adc r26, r1
 126:   b1 1d           adc r27, r1
 128:   80 93 04 01     sts 0x0104, r24
 12c:   90 93 05 01     sts 0x0105, r25
 130:   a0 93 06 01     sts 0x0106, r26
 134:   b0 93 07 01     sts 0x0107, r27
}
 138:   bf 91           pop r27
 13a:   af 91           pop r26
 13c:   9f 91           pop r25
 13e:   8f 91           pop r24
 140:   3f 91           pop r19
 142:   2f 91           pop r18
 144:   0f 90           pop r0
 146:   0f be           out 0x3f, r0    ; 63
 148:   0f 90           pop r0
 14a:   1f 90           pop r1
 14c:   18 95           reti

0000014e <millis>:

unsigned long millis()
{
    unsigned long m;
    uint8_t oldSREG = SREG;
 14e:   8f b7           in  r24, 0x3f   ; 63

    // disable interrupts while we read timer0_millis or we might get an
    // inconsistent value (e.g. in the middle of a write to timer0_millis)
    cli();
 150:   f8 94           cli
    m = timer0_millis;
 152:   20 91 08 01     lds r18, 0x0108
 156:   30 91 09 01     lds r19, 0x0109
 15a:   40 91 0a 01     lds r20, 0x010A
 15e:   50 91 0b 01     lds r21, 0x010B
    SREG = oldSREG;
 162:   8f bf           out 0x3f, r24   ; 63

    return m;
}
 164:   b9 01           movw    r22, r18
 166:   ca 01           movw    r24, r20
 168:   08 95           ret

0000016a <init>:

void init()
{
    // this needs to be called before setup() or some functions won't
    // work there
    sei();
 16a:   78 94           sei

    // on the ATmega168, timer 0 is also used for fast hardware pwm
    // (using phase-correct PWM would mean that timer 0 overflowed half as often
    // resulting in different millis() behavior on the ATmega8 and ATmega168)
#if defined(TCCR0A) && defined(WGM01)
    sbi(TCCR0A, WGM01);
 16c:   84 b5           in  r24, 0x24   ; 36
 16e:   82 60           ori r24, 0x02   ; 2
 170:   84 bd           out 0x24, r24   ; 36
    sbi(TCCR0A, WGM00);
 172:   84 b5           in  r24, 0x24   ; 36
 174:   81 60           ori r24, 0x01   ; 1
 176:   84 bd           out 0x24, r24   ; 36
    // this combination is for the standard atmega8
    sbi(TCCR0, CS01);
    sbi(TCCR0, CS00);
#elif defined(TCCR0B) && defined(CS01) && defined(CS00)
    // this combination is for the standard 168/328/1280/2560
    sbi(TCCR0B, CS01);
 178:   85 b5           in  r24, 0x25   ; 37
 17a:   82 60           ori r24, 0x02   ; 2
 17c:   85 bd           out 0x25, r24   ; 37
    sbi(TCCR0B, CS00);
 17e:   85 b5           in  r24, 0x25   ; 37
 180:   81 60           ori r24, 0x01   ; 1
 182:   85 bd           out 0x25, r24   ; 37

    // enable timer 0 overflow interrupt
#if defined(TIMSK) && defined(TOIE0)
    sbi(TIMSK, TOIE0);
#elif defined(TIMSK0) && defined(TOIE0)
    sbi(TIMSK0, TOIE0);
 184:   ee e6           ldi r30, 0x6E   ; 110
 186:   f0 e0           ldi r31, 0x00   ; 0
 188:   80 81           ld  r24, Z
 18a:   81 60           ori r24, 0x01   ; 1
 18c:   80 83           st  Z, r24
    // this is better for motors as it ensures an even waveform
    // note, however, that fast pwm mode can achieve a frequency of up
    // 8 MHz (with a 16 MHz clock) at 50% duty cycle

#if defined(TCCR1B) && defined(CS11) && defined(CS10)
    TCCR1B = 0;
 18e:   e1 e8           ldi r30, 0x81   ; 129
 190:   f0 e0           ldi r31, 0x00   ; 0
 192:   10 82           st  Z, r1

    // set timer 1 prescale factor to 64
    sbi(TCCR1B, CS11);
 194:   80 81           ld  r24, Z
 196:   82 60           ori r24, 0x02   ; 2
 198:   80 83           st  Z, r24
#if F_CPU >= 8000000L
    sbi(TCCR1B, CS10);
 19a:   80 81           ld  r24, Z
 19c:   81 60           ori r24, 0x01   ; 1
 19e:   80 83           st  Z, r24
    sbi(TCCR1, CS10);
#endif
#endif
    // put timer 1 in 8-bit phase correct pwm mode
#if defined(TCCR1A) && defined(WGM10)
    sbi(TCCR1A, WGM10);
 1a0:   e0 e8           ldi r30, 0x80   ; 128
 1a2:   f0 e0           ldi r31, 0x00   ; 0
 1a4:   80 81           ld  r24, Z
 1a6:   81 60           ori r24, 0x01   ; 1
 1a8:   80 83           st  Z, r24

    // set timer 2 prescale factor to 64
#if defined(TCCR2) && defined(CS22)
    sbi(TCCR2, CS22);
#elif defined(TCCR2B) && defined(CS22)
    sbi(TCCR2B, CS22);
 1aa:   e1 eb           ldi r30, 0xB1   ; 177
 1ac:   f0 e0           ldi r31, 0x00   ; 0
 1ae:   80 81           ld  r24, Z
 1b0:   84 60           ori r24, 0x04   ; 4
 1b2:   80 83           st  Z, r24

    // configure timer 2 for phase correct pwm (8-bit)
#if defined(TCCR2) && defined(WGM20)
    sbi(TCCR2, WGM20);
#elif defined(TCCR2A) && defined(WGM20)
    sbi(TCCR2A, WGM20);
 1b4:   e0 eb           ldi r30, 0xB0   ; 176
 1b6:   f0 e0           ldi r31, 0x00   ; 0
 1b8:   80 81           ld  r24, Z
 1ba:   81 60           ori r24, 0x01   ; 1
 1bc:   80 83           st  Z, r24
#if defined(ADCSRA)
    // set a2d prescale factor to 128
    // 16 MHz / 128 = 125 KHz, inside the desired 50-200 KHz range.
    // XXX: this will not work properly for other clock speeds, and
    // this code should use F_CPU to determine the prescale factor.
    sbi(ADCSRA, ADPS2);
 1be:   ea e7           ldi r30, 0x7A   ; 122
 1c0:   f0 e0           ldi r31, 0x00   ; 0
 1c2:   80 81           ld  r24, Z
 1c4:   84 60           ori r24, 0x04   ; 4
 1c6:   80 83           st  Z, r24
    sbi(ADCSRA, ADPS1);
 1c8:   80 81           ld  r24, Z
 1ca:   82 60           ori r24, 0x02   ; 2
 1cc:   80 83           st  Z, r24
    sbi(ADCSRA, ADPS0);
 1ce:   80 81           ld  r24, Z
 1d0:   81 60           ori r24, 0x01   ; 1
 1d2:   80 83           st  Z, r24

    // enable a2d conversions
    sbi(ADCSRA, ADEN);
 1d4:   80 81           ld  r24, Z
 1d6:   80 68           ori r24, 0x80   ; 128
 1d8:   80 83           st  Z, r24
    // here so they can be used as normal digital i/o; they will be
    // reconnected in Serial.begin()
#if defined(UCSRB)
    UCSRB = 0;
#elif defined(UCSR0B)
    UCSR0B = 0;
 1da:   10 92 c1 00     sts 0x00C1, r1
#endif
}
 1de:   08 95           ret

000001e0 <main>:
#include <Arduino.h>

int main(void)
 1e0:   cf 93           push    r28
 1e2:   df 93           push    r29
{
    init();
 1e4:   0e 94 b5 00     call    0x16a   ; 0x16a <init>

#if defined(USBCON)
    USBDevice.attach();
#endif

    setup();
 1e8:   0e 94 53 00     call    0xa6    ; 0xa6 <setup>

    for (;;) {
        loop();
        if (serialEventRun) serialEventRun();
 1ec:   c0 e0           ldi r28, 0x00   ; 0
 1ee:   d0 e0           ldi r29, 0x00   ; 0
#endif

    setup();

    for (;;) {
        loop();
 1f0:   0e 94 54 00     call    0xa8    ; 0xa8 <loop>
        if (serialEventRun) serialEventRun();
 1f4:   20 97           sbiw    r28, 0x00   ; 0
 1f6:   e1 f3           breq    .-8         ; 0x1f0 <main+0x10>
 1f8:   0e 94 00 00     call    0   ; 0x0 <__vectors>
 1fc:   f9 cf           rjmp    .-14        ; 0x1f0 <main+0x10>

000001fe <_exit>:
 1fe:   f8 94           cli

00000200 <__stop_program>:
 200:   ff cf           rjmp    .-2         ; 0x200 <__stop_program>
```

Comment: Wow, great answer! +1

Comment: 1) The four `sts` should not be counted as call overhead: this is the cost of storing the result in a volatile variable, which you would normally not do. 2) On my system (Arduino 1.0.5, gcc 4.8.2), I don't have the `movw`s. Then the cost of calling `millis()` is: 4 cycles of call overhead + 15 cycles in `millis()` itself = 19 cycles total (≈ 1.188 µs @ 16 MHz).

Comment: @EdgarBonet - That doesn't make sense, `x` is a `uint16_t`. It should be 2 copies at most if that is the cause. Anyways, the question is how long does `millis()` take *when used*, not when called while ignoring the result. Since any practical use is going to involve doing something with the result, I forced the result to be stored via `volatile`. Normally, the same effect would be achieved by the later use of the variable that is set to the return value of the call, but I didn't want to have that extra call taking up space in the answer.

Comment: This `uint16_t` in the source does not match the assembly (4 bytes stored into RAM). You probably posted the source and disassembly of two different versions.

Comment: @ConnorWolf Amazing answer and explanation. Thank you!

Answer (score 8):

Write a sketch that millis 1000 times, not by making a loop, but by copy and paste. Measure that and compare it to the actual expected time. Mind you that that the results may vary with different versions of the IDE (and its compiler in particular).

Another option is to toggle an IO pin before and after the millis call, then measure the time for a very small value and a somewhat larger value. Compare the measured timings and calculate the overhead.

The most accurate way is to take a look at the disassembly listing, the generated code. But that is not for the faint of heart. You'll have to carefully study the datasheet how long each instruction cycle takes.

Comment: How would you measure the time taken by 1000 `millis()` calls?

Comment: You do know millis() is supplied by an interrupt on timer0 that increments an internal variable every tick?

Comment: @TheDoctor I mixed up with `delay`, you are right. But the idea stays the same, you can time a large number of calls and average them. Turning off the interrupts globally may not be a very good idea though ;o)

Comment: Make sure your data set is large enough as printing characters to the Serial take a few milliseconds themselves. I don't remember the exact time, but I think it's something like ~0.6ms per character sent to Serial.

Comment: @Steven10172 you can time an empty string against a 1000-times string (or more), then you know the delta and the measurement is more accurate.

Answer (score 3):

I second calling millis repeatedly and then comparing actual vs. expected.

There will be some minimal overhead, but it will diminish in significance the more times you call millis().

If you look at

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\Arduino ERW 1.0.5\hardware\arduino\cores\arduino\wiring.c
```

You can see that millis() is very tiny at only 4 instructions `(cli is simply # define cli()  \__asm__ \__volatile__ ("cli" ::))` and a return.

I'd call it about 10 million times using a FOR loop which has a volatile as the conditional. The volatile keyword will prevent the compiler from attempting any optimization on the loop itself.

I don't guarantee the following to be syntactically perfect..

```
int temp1,temp2;
temp1=millis();
for (volatile unsigned int j=0;j<1000000;++j){
temp2=millis();}
Serial.print("Execution time = ");
Serial.print((temp2-temp1,DEC);
Serial.print("ms");
```

my guess is that takes ~900ms or about 56us per call to millis. ( I don't have an aruduino handy ATM.

Comment: You should change `int temp1,temp2;` to `volatile int temp1,temp2;` to prevent the compiler from potentially optimizing them away.

Comment: Good call on the volatile. I definitely meant to put that in and then didn't.
I should have also mentioned that the way to do a more proper benchmark is to run an empty loop, record that execution time, then run the loop again while doing work. Subtract the difference, divide by the number of iterations, and there is your highly accurate execution time.

Comment: That kind of benchmark only works on a system that does not **ever** pre-empt your code execution. The arduino environment *by default* has periodic interrupts that will execute periodically. A better solution would be to toggle a pin on every execution, and use a high-resolution timer of some sort to measure the toggle rate when running and not running the code in question, take the *minimum* execution time over a number of samples for each, subtract the baseline, and treat *that* as your execution time. Assuming your execution time is shorter then the minimum time-between interrupts.